# A riddle, short and sweet

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Though I can not decide,
>   My domain is endless and complete.
>   All around you I hide,
>   And to a new age I lead.
>
> Enigmatic I might appear,
>   Superior to my rival.
>   My inventor was quite queer,
>   And stopped a war with my arrival.

Comment: Sorry, I'm voting to close this riddle as too broad. Three of the answers given so far have all fit equally well; [as I said](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42050/a-riddle-short-and-sweet#comment124970_42052), you need to [edit] this riddle to add more lines and narrow down the field of possibilities. If you ping me when you've done so, I'll retract my vote to close :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like a

> Turing reference in several spots.

Are you a

> Turing machine?

Though I can not decide,

> References [Decision Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem)

My domain is endless and complete.

> References [Turing Completeness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)

All around you I hide,
And to a new age I lead.

> Computer languages are mostly Turing complete.

Enigmatic I might appear,
Superior to my rival.

> References the Enigma and the bombe

My inventor was quite queer,
And stopped a war with my arrival.

> Turing was gay and his invention of [the bombe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe) stopped the war earlier.

Comment: This is the answer I had in mind.

Comment: @Arthelais, cool! And welcome to puzzling!

Answer (score 8):

Are you, by any chance?

> Donald Trump?

Though I can not decide,

> Donald Trump has a history of [conflicting](http://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2016/05/donald-trump-2016-contradictions-213869) and changing his [statements](http://www.nbcnews.com/politics/2016-election/full-list-donald-trump-s-rapidly-changing-policy-positions-n547801),

My domain is endless and complete.

> Donald Trump's emporium is quite extensive, especially from his own point of view

All around you I hide,

> Wherever I look or whatever site I visit, I see *something* about him these days.

And to a new age I lead.

> Donald Trump has stated before that he'll 'Make America Great Again' which is in line with the 'New Age' he'll 'lead' America into.

Enigmatic I might appear,

> Donald is convinced he's an enigmatic personality

Superior to my rival.

> I'm not even going to defend this one

My inventor was quite queer,

> I'm going with a cryptic version of inventor aka father with the old (original) meaning of queer: unique and special.

And stopped a war with my arrival.

> Donald is 'heavily' against the invasions im the middle east and has said that he wishes to pull back the US forces from there.

Also, as a disclaimer:

> I **do not** agree with all of this logic, some of these answers are from Donald Trump's own point of view (since the OP has stated the riddle in first person, I just found them suiting in a certain context to Trump. This does not reflect my personal politic views.

Comment: Donald Trump appears to be the answer to everything :P

Comment: This answer seems to be invalid now, after the latest edit to the riddle (Donald Trump didn't have an inventor). You might want to delete it?

Comment: Not quite yet my friend.. Not quite yet

Comment: Of course this is not the answer, but very creative.

Comment: _"Not quite yet my friend.. Not quite yet"_ -- @Roberrrt, do you mean _"you are not there yet?"_ ;)

Comment: Haha, it ment that I could still portray Trump in this riddleb:)

Answer (score 8):

It is clearly a

> Turing Machine

```
Though I can not decide,
```

> Turing demonstrated the indecidability of certain problems with the Halting Problem

```
My domain is endless and complete.
```

> Turing machines use a theoretically infinite instruction tape, and can be used to solve any computable problem.

```
All around you I hide,
```

> Turing machines are the basis for all modern computing, which is everywhere

```
And to a new age I lead.
```

> leading straight to the Information Age

```
Enigmatic I might appear,
```

> The ideas are a little odd, and one of the early uses was in cracking the Enigma

```
Superior to my rival.
```

> Widely considered superior to a similar theorem by Church involving Lamda Calculus

```
My inventor was quite queer,
```

> Turing was prosecuted for homosexuality

```
And stopped a war with my arrival.
```

> The Bombe devices constructed by Turing and others to decrypt Enigma are credited with shortening the WWII by several years.

Comment: You were not the first with the answer, but your solution was spot on for every line.

Answer (score 7):

> Space?

Though I can not decide
My domain is endless and complete.

> This may refer to something like the multiverse theory

All around you I hide

> Space is all around us

And to a new age I lead.

> The Space Age!

Enigmatic I might appear,

> Space is a mystery

Superior to my rival.

> Maybe water? Water could be the rival because it was traveled before space, but you're stuck on the planet if you travel by water. Therefore, you must *Trek* to the *Star*s.

My inventor was quite queer,

> You could say that, I guess.. o_o (Queer meaning unique. :P)

And stopped a war with my arrival.

> It's a trope that when the space age comes, humanity will have made peace with itself.

Comment: Who's the 'inventor' of space?

Comment: @randal'thor [This guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God).

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Time?

Though I can not decide,

> It can't make decisions on its own but we need time to make ours.

My domain is endless and complete.

> We all live in time.

All around you I hide,

> Yes, it is all around us.

And to a new age I lead.

> And time, as it goes by, leads us to the future.

Comment: Not the answer I had in mind, but valid nonetheless!

Comment: @Arthelais If more than one possible answer fits the riddle as written, I recommend you edit it (e.g. by adding more lines) so that there's a unique solution. Otherwise I'm afraid it may get closed as too broad.

Comment: @randal'thor While his answer was technically valid, there is a much more precise and fitting answer. I will add four more lines if no one has figured it out in a few hours.

Comment: This answer seems to be invalid now, after the latest edit to the riddle (time didn't have an inventor). You might want to delete it?

Comment: @randal'thor I guess I can, but then again why should I try to accommodate ill conceived riddles?

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Silicon

Though I can not decide,

> We are the brain behind them to decide.

My domain is endless and complete.

> not sure about it.

All around you I hide,

> Silicon all around us [PDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_digital_assistant)

And to a new age I lead.

> The Silicon age

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> The Internet

Though I can not decide

> We're the one surfing on the web

My domain is endless and complete.

> We can suppose that it is true

All around you I hide,

> [Internet is all around us](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/12/a-network-of-fragments/419469/)

And to a new age I lead.

> The computer age, yay!